# why token is not create in node js csrf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf, nodejs-server

could you please tell me why token is not create in node js csrf ?

I am using this package to `generate token and verify token`
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/csrf

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-resonance-3y8zc

```
var http = require("http");
var Tokens = require("csrf");
var secret = Tokens.secretSync();
var token = Tokens.create(secret);

console.log("token", token);
//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.write("Hello World!"); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

I am getting error

**Tokens.secretSync is not a function**

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate an instance of `Tokens`.

```
var Tokens = require("csrf");

var tokens = new Tokens();

var secret = tokens.secretSync();
var token = tokens.create(secret);
```

Comment: how to verify /..??

Comment: how to verify this token ?

Comment: If you're confused about how to manage the CSRF flow, you should consider something a bit more high level than this library. Perhaps swap out `http` for [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and `csrf` for a middleware like [csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf)